# How to raise Exception from C# .NET COM

Tags: c#, delphi, com, delphi-7

How to raise Exception from a C# .NET COM. In fact I'm inside a Win32 application build using Borland Delphi 7.0 and I'm try to consume a function in .NET. Everything is working fine except the fact raising exception in C# are not re-routed to Delphi, I guess I miss some kind of method decorator. Here a piece of code:

```
void iLinkV2.FindLinkedClientEng(string SourceApp, string SourceClientID,
     ref object ClientID, ref object Engagement)
{
    throw new COMException("errClientNotFound",
        (int)ExceptionsType.errClientNotFound);
    ClientID  = SourceClientID; 
}

[ComVisible(true),
 Guid("D731C821-EEA2-446E-BC5A-441DCA0477F5"),
 InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface iLinkV2
{ ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to. Exceptions are not part of COM Interop specification and should not cross module boundaries. You can use status codes to indicate any errors.

Catch the exception just before method exits (in each COM interface method). Turn the result into an error code. If you use an `HRESULT` then you can consume it as `safecall` and get the Delphi compiler to re-raise an exception on the other side of the fence.

Comment: Not sure you donlt need to would be the way I'd decsribe it. You can't would be closer.

Comment: Thanks, I was confuse because I was looking at a Delphi COM at first and since Delphi is able to manage exception re-routing I was thinking that obviously that .Net was able to do the same.